# What is the exact location of nagesh jyotirlinga?

Tags: shiva, india, jyotirlinga

There is a controversy regarding the location of Nagesvara Jyotirlinga. Is it in Jageshwar, Almora (Uttrakhand)? Or is it located in Nageshwara or Darukavana, Dwarka (Gujrat)?

Comment: It's highly debatable. But, popular culture attributes it to around Gujarat. *Darukavanam (दारूकावनं)* being roughly translated as *Dwarikavanam (द्वारकावनं)*. That's another matter though, daruka Etymologically relates to the deodar, which is basically a forest around the *Jageshwara* temple shrines. It's really complicated. Popular culture prevails although no forest (वन) around the *nageshwaram* attributed shrine in the Gujarat.